# Why are circles always created upside down?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

Why is it that when you create a circle, then do a curve deform across that circle, the object always jumps to the opposite side?

Here is what the final result should look like:

[image]

Here is what happens when trying to create that object.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXvMSw_9VRc&feature=youtu.be

How can I simplify deforming a shape to a curve without having to rotate multiple times?

[Blender File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/460997/Blender/smooshed-copy.blend)

Answer (score 2):

You could also bring the shape into the position (illustarted by the first image) by moving it along the x-axis.
<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>  followed by mouse movement.

[image]